# What was the intended ending of Monty Python and the Holy Grail?

Tags: monty-python, holy-grail

I've heard from many sources that the ending to Monty Python and the Holy Grail (where it abruptly ends just before an invasion on the French castle, due to the police arriving to arrest the cast) was put in at the last moment because they were essentially out of money.

This doesn't really strike me as true, given the foreshadowing that built up to it (the historian scenes).  I suppose they could have been filmed later as well and interspersed, but the impression I had always had was that they just cut the last bits of the movie, replacing them with the arrest scene, not filmed several other short scenes to mix in earlier.

Is this the case?  Were all those scenes last-minute changes?  If so, what was the original ending supposed to be?

Comment: Just as a note: scenes are rarely (if ever) shot in sequence, and it's not uncommon at all for scenes to be added or changed in a film to support a reworked ending.

Comment: Remember many sketches in their TV series ended like that.  The "I Would Like to Buy an Argument" sketch, for example, ends deus ex machina of an officer stopping the sketch.  British comedy does not always worry about resolving the story (watch Britcoms for a while and you'll see that they sometimes end with a major punchline to a situation than resolving the plot).  Monty Python often went through the funny bits they liked, then just found an excuse to cut the skit off after they were out of ideas.  It wouldn't surprise me if this is how they handled their movie scripts, too.

Comment: @Mark: I know, but I had always gotten the impression that the only scene they modified was the ending one.  The inclusion of the earlier scenes is what made me question the urban legend.

Comment: @Jeff, I presume with your high rep, you know that the checkmark can be moved. :) While I have nothing against DKuntz2's answer, I have to say that Gilles' answer is better, much more in-depth. (I usually wait a few days before checkmarking, personally...)

Comment: @John C: Yeah, I do :)  I agree with you, I just kinda didn't expect anything better than an answer sourced from the script itself.  Then, of course, Gilles hit a home run.

Comment: I remember seeing the movie, initial release, at a theater in Maryland. The movie ended with Arthur being taken off by the police which abruptly cut to an old super 8mm film of "See America in a RV" from the 50's for at least 25 minutes. It was so seamless no one in the theater could tell if it was part of the movie. People sat still for about 5 minutes then started looking around sort of bewildered. After 15 minutes some people started to get up slowly while still looking at the screen and moving towards the aisle to leave. I left after about 25 minutes of waiting for the punch line.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Now you've gone and made me watch the extras on my DVD again.

In a 1974 BBC documentary made during the filming, Terry Jones says that the plot was completely finalized before filming:

> Yeah, I think the Pythons, we usually stick fairly closely to the script, actually. They're usually pretty careful to work out, because they're so involved, usually, you have to stick, you have to work everything out in advance.

Michael Palin confirms; the plot was fixed in advance, but the details of each scene could be improvised:

> It's very scripted. And then we get together, and then just about ten minutes before a take, the script is slightly rewritten. And five minutes before the take it's fairly radically rewritten. So in fact at the very last minute there's usually these little extra bits creep in.

Graham Chapman reveals a bit of the plot in his interview:

> It's about a search for the Holy Grail (…). People are trying to find this Grail. — Do they? — No. No. — Isn't that rather a letdown? Don't you feel the audience… — It's a big letdown. The whole film has a great anti-climax.

Before filming began, the script underwent a lot of change. John Cleese estimates that no more than 15% of the original script remained by the time filming started. At some point, the plan was to have half the movie happen in the Middle-Ages and the other half in modern times. This is about when the quest for the Holy Grail became the main plot thread; at that stage it was to be found in [Harrods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harrods) (because they have everything).

The historian sequences were added at some point during the writing, well after the first draft. The first historian scene was originally Michael Palin's idea, to speed the plot along. As the scene seemed to go well, the theme was expanded to tie up the plot.

Michael Palin also came up early with the idea to end the film with the police arresting everyone. In *The Quest for the Holy Grail Locations*, a 2001 documentary, [Julian Doyle](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0236405/) (production manager, special effects photographer, and the police sergeant who directs the final arrest and covers the camera lens with his hand to stop the film) mentions that he very much liked the idea of the ending (I don't remember if he specifically came up with it).

I didn't hear any mention that the cost was a motivation for cutting parts of the script. Whether it was or not, the ending was clearly planned well before filming began, for artistic reasons to boot, so it's not a case of running out of money.

Answer (score 51):

Regarding the end of Monty Python and the Holy Grail, according to page 248 of the 2003 edition of Thomas Dunne Books [*The Pythons autobiography by the Pythons*](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/697789.The_Pythons_Autobiography):

> Eric Idle-  ...and only at the end do you realise there's no plot whatsoever. **We didn't know how to end it.** I contributed the ending because I said,
> "You should just stop it. The police should come in and arrest
> everybody, and there's a hand on the lens.' My daughter hates that
> end, she says, 'Is that the end? That it? I hate that." **Well we
> couldn't afford the battle.** We had all these university students on £4
> a day and they shot them every angle they could, but there
> weren't many of them at all.

So, if you believe Eric's account, the movie ended the way it was written, and it was written that way because they couldn't afford to hire enough extras at £4 a day to film a convincing battle scene. No matter how many camera angles they used to film the few students they did have, it wasn't enough. Using the police to end the picture was a cheaper and much easier solution.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised that this answer is so lowly voted; it seems to say the same as the others (that it was the original ending in the film), but also hits the source of the rumour - that it _was_ written that way because of budget...

Comment: @Izkata I liken my answer to a parrot. It's a good parrot, but it's a dead parrot.

Comment: @MajorStackings - I'll give you a vote, mate.

Comment: I challenge the authenticity of this source. The date of launch of the Euro currency was 1999 and Monty Python was released in 1975. The university students could not have been paid in Euros.

Comment: @JackG that's a pound symbol (£), not euro (€)

Comment: @Izkata I suppose because it contradicts the accepted answer in two points: one major (that the ending was written before the movie was shot, not because they couldn't afford the budget) and one minor (that it was Michael Palin, not Eric Idle, who came up with the idea). (Also, another person [claims](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/5160/770) they hold a copy of the first draft of the Holy Grail, and it features the police ending).

Comment: @AndresF. I don't think they're necessarily contradictory.  Eric doesn't say that they considered the budget only _after_ writing had finished and filming had started.  They may not have known the detail of £4/day during the writing phase, but they may well have had a rough idea that a huge battle scene wouldn't have been feasible on the sort of budget they were likely to get.

Answer (score 40):

I have no idea why, but I have a copy of the first draft of the Holy Grail.

The ending is the original ending. They didn't change that, but they took out the parts that lead up to it in the script. Originally an inspector was going to be following them around and attempting to find them, and does, at the end.

Source:
Monty Python and The Holy Grail (Book) A First Draft by all of the Python members.

Comment: There is still a little of that in the film - you see the police visiting scenes from earlier in the film in short flashes.

Answer (score 2):

In the book *All the Words*, which is about *Monty Python's Flying Circus*, it's told how the episode "Michael Ellis" incorporated some unused material originally intended for *Monty Python and the Holy Grail*.

"Michael Ellis" is a rare episode that's one continuous sketch, set in a department store. This makes use of a rejected section of MP:HG set in Harrods, where King Arthur would find the Holy Grail in the store's Grail Hall.

Answer (score 0):

The Python script book for Holy Grail has two scripts. The original draft actually has a much different ending. It's been transcribed here: http://www.angelfire.com/movies/closedcaptioned/grail.txt

This is not to contradict others who said the ending was what was in the original shooting script.

Comment: The linked script has the same ending as the movie.

Answer (score 0):

I can't confirm this, but I only have my memory to inform this comment:

When I was a kid in the 70's, my brother got a book from the library that (as I recall) was the original script of the movie, which was written before the final season of Monty Python's Flying Circus got made. It was VERY different from the movie, featuring substantial sections that ended up being in the final season of the show (the Michael Ellis episode featured prominently in it).

The original ending of Holy Grail was that they battle their way into Castle Argh and find the Grail. Smash cut to Arthur and Bedevere on the boat, sailing away from the castle in victory. Arthur says to Bedevere, "Hand me... the Grail." Bedevere responds, "I thought you had it." The end.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. We love to be able to fact check things here, so if you could look up the title of the book you mentioned and add it to this answer, it would greatly improve it.